# Finding the URL to be used to check if plugin is installed with a theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I understand the following code checks if a plugin is installed and if not it puts an error in the backend of WP:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessages');

function showAdminMessages()
{
    $plugin_messages = array();

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// Download the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin
if(!is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ))
{
    $plugin_messages[] = 'This theme requires you to install the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin, <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/">download it from here</a>.';
}

// Download the Disqus comment system
if(!is_plugin_active( 'disqus-comment-system/disqus.php' ))
{
    $plugin_messages[] = 'This theme requires you to install the Disqus comment system plugin, <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/">download it from here</a>.';
}

if(count($plugin_messages) > 0)
{
    echo '<div id="message" class="error">';

        foreach($plugin_messages as $message)
        {
            echo '<p><strong>'.$message.'</strong></p>';
        }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

}

My question is: how do I find the URL that is used in this line:

```
if(!is_plugin_active( 'disqus-comment-system/disqus.php' ))
```

I am trying to use this code for other plugins not listed in this code snippet, and I have no clue where I find these urls to check if the plugin is used or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This are not url's. They are paths. So disqus-comment-system is the folder of the plugin and disqus.php the "init" php file. Every plugin has the more or less the same structure. Install your desired plugin and check it's file structure inside plugin folder of WP.

Comment: awesome, that is what i was missing. thank you for the clear answer

Comment: You are welcome! I post my comment as an answer to accept it as a solved question.

Answer (score 0):

This are not url's. They are paths. So disqus-comment-system is the folder of the plugin and disqus.php the "init" php file. Every plugin has more or less the same structure. Install your desired plugin and check it's file structure inside plugin folder of WP.

More: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active